# How to change some string to its other form?

Tags: regex, notepad++, removing-whitespace

I have some string that looks like:

```
string1 string2 number1 number2 string3
```

and need to change it to:
`string1 string2,number1,number2` (without string3)

or:

`string1 number1 number2 string2` >> `string1,number1,number2` (without string2)

I used `(\D*\s|\-\D*)\s*(\d{2}.\d{3})\s*(\d{2}.\d{3})(\D)` to find matching strings, and `$1,$2,$3;` to get the final form, but was unsuccessful.

In string:

```
 Aleksandrów Kujawski 52.880  18.700  Kujawsko-Pomorskie 
 Aleksandrów Łódzki 51.820  19.299  Łódzkie 
 Andrychów 49.860  19.339  Małopolskie 
 Augustów 53.839  23.000  Podlaskie
```

It changed it to:

```
 Aleksandrów Kujawski ,52.880,18.700; Kujawsko-Pomorskie 
 Aleksandrów Łódzki ,51.820,19.299; Łódzkie 
 Andrychów ,49.860,19.339; Małopolskie 
 Augustów ,53.839,23.000; Podlaskie
```

What should looks like:

```
Aleksandrów Kujawski,52.880,18.700;
Aleksandrów Łódzki,51.820,19.299;
Andrychów,49.860,19.339;
Augustów,53.839,23.000;
```

Any hints?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I need to cleat data in notepad++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do in notepad++:

Fin what: `^(\s*\S+(?:\s+\D+)?)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+).*`
Replace with: `$1,$2,$3;`

Comment: not working. Tied `(\S+\s+\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)`, but somethimes get last words from previous line.
There are spaces in begining of every line, maybe it matters...

Comment: This one wokrs. Thanks.

Comment: @bqr: Glad it helped. Feel free to accept the answer.